# Is there a simple way to get array of all arguments that do not begin with a hyphen?

Tags: zsh, options

Zsh includes a powerful utility for parsing command line options,`zparseopts`.
Is there an easy way to extract the array of all the command line arguments that don't begin with a hyphen?

Comment: ok, searching online i came across something like `nohyph=(${argv##-*})`.  I'm not sure how robust it is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter the positional parameters `$@` with the [parameter expansion suffix](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) `:#-*` to strip elements matching the pattern `-*` and the [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `@` inside double quotes to preserve empty elements. Add the `M` flag to retain only the elements that match the pattern.

```
non_hyphen_arguments=("${(@)@:#-*}")
hyphen_arguments=("${(@M)@:#-*}")
```

However this is not a good way of parsing command line arguments; for example, given

```
myscript hello -a world
```

you will get `hello` and `world` in `non_hyphen_arguments` and `-a` in `hyphen_arguments`.

The simpler form of argument parsing, with single-letter options, is [`getopts`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-getopts).

Comment: The `(@)` is redundant for `$@` or `$argv[@]`, you'd need it for `$argv`.